# msg to eml format conversion

Tags: email, outlook

I'm searching for a method to convert msg files to eml format. I have Outlook 2010 but it appears only possible to save as msg. I did find some third party tools that can be used but I prefer not to use a third party tool - if possible.

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: I know what you mean, but "msg" and "eml" are not strictly well-defined terms.  I guess you want to convert Microsoft's proprietary internal format to honest-to-Jon-Postel RFC5322 format.  As far as I can tell, the only way to get that out of Outlook is by sending the messages you want to export as attachments (not forwards) and then open them in a real email client (and even then, if your server is Exchange, you don't really know what you will get).  Not a programming question anyway.

Comment: Yes -  thanks... not exactly programming but if it's possible through powershell or vba - that's something to explore...

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a quick and dirty VB script, [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is probably your only option. Other options are [IConverterSession](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff960231.aspx) (C++ or Delphi only) or explicitly building the MIME file one line at a time from various message properties (`MailItem` can be returned by calling [Namespace.OpenSharedItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869733.aspx) in the Outlook Object Model).

```
  set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
  Session.Logon 'not needed if you don't need to convert EX addresses to SMTP
  set Msg = Session.GetMessageFromMsgFile("c:\temp.test.msg")
  Msg.SaveAs "c:\temp.test.eml", 1031
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a free tool for bulk conversion I created a while back: [MSG2EML](https://deconf.com/msg-to-eml-converter-freeware/).

It simply converts all MSG files to EML on a given folder.

Answer (score -2):

MSG file and EML file both formats are used for containing the email with the attachment, but different from each other. EML extension used by multiple email clients, other hand MSG file only used by Outlook email client. In your scenario, you need an effective way to convert multiple MSG files to EML format, by using Outlook email client you can easily convert MSG file to EML format by using save as option of Outlook email client, but this way cannot convert their attachment.